# Error generating XML from an XSD (Using xsd.exe) VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd

well look what I'm trying to do is build a XML through an XSD for this I am using a class that I built with the xsd.exe tool (VOUCHER_BUILD_VERSION_2.vb) basically has two child nodes MSGDATA and FieldTypes in the class are translated as two properties.

With the first node had no problems since all the children of that node are simple XML fragment that was built with this code:

```
 Dim Addenda As New VOUCHER_BUILD_TypeShape()
 Addenda.FieldTypes = New FieldTypes_TypeShape
        With Addenda.FieldTypes

            .VCHR_BANK_STG = New FieldTypesVCHR_BANK_STG_TypeShape
            With .VCHR_BANK_STG
                .class = "R"
                .BUSINESS_UNIT = New FieldTypesCharFieldType
                ...
            End With
        End With

 Dim xs As New XmlSerializer(GetType(VOUCHER_BUILD_TypeShape))
 Dim fs As New FileStream("C:/filesPS/demo.xml", FileMode.Create)
 xs.Serialize(fs, Addenda)
 fs.Close()
```

What generates the following XML:

```
<VOUCHER_BUILD xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <FieldTypes>
           <VCHR_VNDR_STG class="R">
                 <BUSINESS_UNIT type="CHAR"/>
                 ...
           </VCHR_VNDR_STG>
     </FieldTypes>
</VOUCHER>
```

The issue is with the other node (MSGDATA) is a complex type that the result in XML is expected that node:

```
<MsgData>
    <Transaction>
        <VCHR_HDR_STG class="R">
            <BUSINESS_UNIT>MEX01</BUSINESS_UNIT>
            ...
        </VCHR_HDR_STG>
        <PSCAMA class="R">
            <LANGUAGE_CD/>
            <AUDIT_ACTN>A</AUDIT_ACTN>
            ...
        </PSCAMA>
        ...
    </Transaction>
</MsgData>
```

As I am trying to create:

First I created the MSGDATA node:

```
 Dim oTransaction_TypeShape(0) As Transaction_TypeShape
 Addenda.MsgData = oTransaction_TypeShape
```

That works, after FieldTypes node puts me at least

After trying to place the content:

```
 Dim oTransaction_TypeShape(0) As Transaction_TypeShape
'THIS LINE IS THAT I'M ADDING THAT THEORY IS NODE VCHR_HDR_STG
 oTransaction_TypeShape(0).VCHR_HDR_STG = New VCHR_HDR_STGMsgDataRecord_TypeShape
 Addenda.MsgData = oTransaction_TypeShape
```

When compiling does not mark any error. But it throws this error when running: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It seems something really simple but I've already failed to solve.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved, the error was an attribute that had no value (Nothing):

```
Dim oTransaction_TypeShape(0) As Transaction_TypeShape 

oTransaction_TypeShape(0) = New Transaction_TypeShape

oTransaction_TypeShape(0).VCHR_HDR_STG = New VCHR_HDR_STGMsgDataRecord_TypeShape
```